# Install fifa in ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: games

my system is dell inspiron1525. I want to install fifa13 or 12 in my laptop.I use ubuntu14.04.Show me the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wine:

- Download Fifa 13
- Install wine through the terminal using `sudo apt-get install wine`
- Locate the Fifa executable and right-click it, selecting "Open With -> Wine"

[WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14533) reports that Fifa 13 works on Linux, so the above should set it up okay for you.

Comment: A link to the winehq page would help - appdb pages also often have tips in case the install does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Install wine using command "*sudo apt-get install wine*" and then go to your hard drive where fifa's file is located and click on .exe file. Now the setup will run like in Windows. Cool!